# Getting data over time grouped by latest related_id for each interval

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that retrieves cumulative results over time that only fetches the latest instance of a result set per interval for each related id.

Example:

Imagine there is a users table, and each user can create reports with issues in them. The issues get aggregated in an report_totals table with a sum of the issue category in them. The tables might look something like this

```
users
id, email

reports
id, user_id, date

report_totals
id, report_id, errors, alerts
```

Here's the part I'm struggling with, if a user hasn't submitted a report in the current time interval, it should backfill that data with the previous interval's sum. So let's say we have data that looks like this

```
reports
1, 1, 2018-1-1
2, 2, 2018-1-1
3, 1, 2018-1-4
4, 1, 2018-2-1
5, 1, 2018-3-1
6, 2, 2018-3-1

report_totals
1, 1, 5, 5
2, 2, 3, 0
3, 3, 2, 0
4, 4, 10, 2
5, 5, 30, 15
6, 6, 1, 2
```

I want to write a query to return results that look like this

```
date, errors, alerts
2018-1-1, 5, 0
2018-2-1, 13, 2
2018-3-1, 31, 17
```

The report interval is 1 month, so it only uses the latest result from each month, for each user, sums them, and will backfill from previous intervals if there isn't a record for that user.

Is something like this possible in MySQL and is it the right way to go about it? Thanks in advance, sorry if this has been answered before, I haven't found anything that quite accomplishes what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It is a tricky problem, but not unsolvable using MySQL :-) It *may* be solved in less verbose query and *possibly performant* manner using [Window functions with Frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html), available in [MySQL version 8.0.2 and above](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/). However, we can also solve this problem using [Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html), using a mix of `CROSS JOIN` and [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html). I will break down the query and try to explain it in steps.

Since you want to consider previous months' reporting values, even if there is no reporting done in the current month, so our first step would be to generate a "Master Table" which basically contains all possible combinations of `user_id` and `first date of a month`. This can be done within the query itself.

We can get all the unique `user_id` values from the `users` table. And, the start dates of all the reporting months can be determined using the following query.

```
SELECT MIN(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')) AS date, 
       MONTH(date) AS month 
FROM reports 
GROUP BY month
```

Now, there may be a possibility that there is no reporting done for a particular month at all. In that case, you will rather have to use a Master Calendar table. However, for practical purposes, it will be extremely rare to have no reporting done at all in a whole month.

Now, we can get all possible combinations using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
(SELECT MIN(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-01')) AS date, 
        MONTH(date) AS month 
 FROM reports 
 GROUP BY month) AS all_mon
CROSS JOIN
users AS u
```

Now, we can use Correlated Subquery to determine `errors` and `alerts` for every row in the above-generated table. We will look for the latest row from the `report_totals` table where the `user_id` matches, and **month** of the reporting being less than or equal to the current **month**. For `errors`, the subquery would look as follows:

```
SELECT rt1.errors 
FROM report_totals AS rt1 
JOIN reports AS r1 ON r1.id = rt1.report_id 
WHERE r1.user_id = u.id AND 
      MONTH(r1.date) <= all_mon.month 
ORDER BY r1.date DESC LIMIT 1
```

A similar subquery would be used for determining the `alerts`.

Finally, we will take this complete result-set as a Derived Table, and do a `GROUP BY` on the month (first date of the month), and compute the `SUM()` on `alerts` and `errors` for all the users.

Final (and complete) query would look as follows:

```
SELECT dt.date,
       Sum(dt.errors) AS errors,
       Sum(dt.alerts) AS alerts
FROM   (SELECT all_mon.date,
               u.id,
               (SELECT rt1.errors
                FROM   report_totals AS rt1
                       JOIN reports AS r1
                         ON r1.id = rt1.report_id
                WHERE  r1.user_id = u.id
                       AND Month(r1.date) <= all_mon.month
                ORDER  BY r1.date DESC
                LIMIT  1) AS errors,
               (SELECT rt1.alerts
                FROM   report_totals AS rt1
                       JOIN reports AS r1
                         ON r1.id = rt1.report_id
                WHERE  r1.user_id = u.id
                       AND Month(r1.date) <= all_mon.month
                ORDER  BY r1.date DESC
                LIMIT  1) AS alerts
        FROM   (SELECT Min(Date_format(date, '%Y-%m-01')) AS date,
                       Month(date)                        AS month
                FROM   reports
                GROUP  BY month) AS all_mon
               CROSS JOIN users AS u) AS dt
GROUP  BY dt.date
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m4bttSaULydGQg27LPzLgY/4)

---

**Result:**

```
| date       | errors | alerts |
| ---------- | ------ | ------ |
| 2018-01-01 | 5      | 0      |
| 2018-02-01 | 13     | 2      |
| 2018-03-01 | 31     | 17     |
```

---

### Edit 1: First Optimization

I did not like the usage of Two similar correlated subqueries to get `errors` and `alerts` separately. But, this is a limitation with MySQL, that it does not allow more than one operand in such subqueries. So instead, as a hack, we can [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) them into a single string, using some delimiter, such as `|`. This will reduce the subqueries to be used into one.

Now, in the outermost query, we can use string functions like [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and [`Cast()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to extract the respective values out as number(s) and do `Sum()` operations accordingly.

**Query #2**

```
SELECT dt.date,
       Sum(Cast(Substring_index(dt.error_alerts, '|', 1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS
       errors,
       Sum(Cast(Substring_index(dt.error_alerts, '|', -1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS
       alerts
FROM   (SELECT all_mon.date,
               u.id,
               (SELECT Concat(rt1.errors, '|', rt1.alerts)
                FROM   report_totals AS rt1
                       JOIN reports AS r1
                         ON r1.id = rt1.report_id
                WHERE  r1.user_id = u.id
                       AND Month(r1.date) <= all_mon.month
                ORDER  BY r1.date DESC
                LIMIT  1) AS error_alerts
        FROM   (SELECT Min(Date_format(date, '%Y-%m-01')) AS date,
                       Month(date)                        AS month
                FROM   reports
                GROUP  BY month) AS all_mon
               CROSS JOIN users AS u) AS dt
GROUP  BY dt.date
```

**Result**

```
| date       | errors | alerts |
| ---------- | ------ | ------ |
| 2018-01-01 | 5      | 0      |
| 2018-02-01 | 13     | 2      |
| 2018-03-01 | 31     | 17     |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m4bttSaULydGQg27LPzLgY/5)

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will work :

```
select r.date,sum(rt.alerts),sum(rt.errors) from reports r join report_totals rt on r.id = rt.report_id group by r.date;
```

Comment: I don't think you read my full requirements.

I need only 1 result per interval, and it should only grab the latest report per user. That query fulfilled none of those requirements. 

Here is a sqlfiddle. Please look at my desired output vs the output from your query.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c142ba/1